# Stuck in an Appliance

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

Some pop-culture knowledge is needed for this one.

> Trapped in my prison, I await my release.
> If I ever escape, I will make all men cease.
>
> Demon, Devil, both are my name.
> Flute, bassoon, I am the same.
>
> My son will fight what we've become,
> Together with God, they will be one.

Who am I?

Hint

> The monkey is my foe,
>  He defeats me with a powerful blow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know enough about the series to fully explain this answer, but I believe you are

> Piccolo from Dragon Ball Z

Trapped in my prison, I await my release.
If I ever escape, I will make all men cease.

> I don't recall whether Piccolo was "trapped" anywhere, but he certainly has the power to destroy all life on Earth.

Demon, Devil, both are my name.
Flute, bassoon, I am the same.

> Don't know the first line, but piccolo, flute, and bassoon are all instruments.

My son will fight what we've become,
Together with God, they will be one.

> Piccolo has a son called Piccolo Jr.

Hint

> Piccolo is defeated by Goku, who is inspired by Sun Wukong and has a simian-like tail.

Title

> Freeza (pronounced "freezer") is the name of another Dragon Ball Z villain.

Comment: Okay, I'm accepting this as the answer since it's technically correct. You're wrong on a few things though.

Demon King Piccolo (or Piccolo Daimao) was trapped in an electric rice cooker by Master Mutaito (Hence the title name). He was called the Demon King, the Devil is king of the demons. Demon King Piccolo does birth Piccolo, and Piccolo Jr. fuses with Kami (which is the literal translation in Japanese for God).

Answer (score 0):

Initial guess :

> The White Bone Demon A.K.A Baigujing

Explanation :

> My first guess would be that the monkey is Sun Wukong A.K.A the Monkey King, and that would make you the White Bone Demon, which is defeated by the Monkey King.

But I can't get that to fit with a son or any flutes etc.